# jQuery ScrollTop working inconsistently across different pages (not functioning on some)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

ScrollTop isn't working on some pages, but others. What's baffling about this issue is that the pages are using the same templates, same Javascript/CSS, etc. This has to be something simple that I'm missing, as I'm completely baffled by this issue. Here is my code:

```
    $("#spot1").click(function() {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#div-1").offset().top-100
    },1000);
});
```

The pages in question are the services pages found under the services menu here: http://www.emerchantbroker.com/

Hoping someone has an answer to my madness. Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: Was trying and saw that your header overflows your body when you make the width of the site smaller then 400px or something like that

Comment: We haven't fully tweaked the mobile experience since implementing these new design changes. It's something we're working on.